# Kubernetes - broadcast a specific http request to every replica instances from the same pod

Tags: kubernetes

I'm really new to kubernetes and I would like to distribute only one specific request received by the ingress controller to every replica instance of a microservice. It's to avoid the load balancing.

My context is that I have two replica for a Java Spring Boot microservice and each of them have singleton, I would like to invoke the same call from each singleton in a specific request like the path below :

https://domaine.xx/path/operationThatBoradcastReplicaPod

It's possible to configure the ingress controller to filter a specific path and do the broadcast ?

Im not in cloud platform like AWS, AZURE, etc.

Thank you in advance for your reply !

Comment: Ingress controller can not do that in any environment. Best will be to use application specific broadcast and use that instead to invoke singleton bean's method in each replica. If you are using k8s, I am presuming you already have some inter service messaging layer that you may use for broadcast (redis, rabbitmq etc). Architecturally it'll be much cleaner solution as well IMHO.

Comment: Having said what I said in my last comment, there's one workaround possible which involves redirects and little bit intelligent handling at spring boot controller layer. Not the best solution still IMO but if you are interested, I can comprehend that in an answer (wouldn't fit in comment).